# C++. Inheritance and initializing member variable has compile error

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization, initializer-list

I'm studying on c++ inheritance and have a question about initializing member variables.

For this question, i wrote the two example code. (below)

**Code 1.** compile success

```
#include <iostream>

class SuperClass{
private:
    int var;
public:
    SuperClass() : var(0) {}
    SuperClass(int arg) : var(arg) {}
    int getVar(){
        return var;
    }
};

class SubClass : public SuperClass{
private:
    int subVar;
public:
    SubClass() : SuperClass(1),subVar(1) {}
    SubClass(int superArg, int subArg) : SuperClass(superArg), subVar(subArg) {}
    void print(){
        std::cout<<getVar()<<" & "<<subVar<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    SubClass object(3,2);
    object.print();

    return 0;
}
```

**Code 2.** has compile error

```
#include <iostream>

class SuperClass{
private:
    int var;
public:
    SuperClass() : var(0) {}
    SuperClass(int arg) : var(arg) {}
    int getVar(){
        return var;
    }
};

class SubClass : public SuperClass{
private:
    int subVar;
public:
    SubClass() : SuperClass(1),subVar(1) {}
    SubClass(int superArg, int subArg) : subVar(subArg) {
        SuperClass(superArg);
    }
    void print(){
        std::cout<<getVar()<<" & "<<subVar<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    SubClass object(3,2);
    object.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Two code above have a difference in calling SuperClass's constructor(SuperClass(arg)).

- 'Code 1' calls SuperClass constructor in the way of initializer list.
- 'Code 2' calls SuperClass constructor in SubClass's constructor body.

I think code 1 & 2 will be compiled successfully but code 2 has compile error.

(Error line number is 20)

And i don't have any idea why Code 2 has compile error.

In my Xcode,

Compile error message is **Redefinition of 'superArg' with a different type: 'SuperClass' vs 'int'**.

What is this message mean and have any C++ syntax that i don't know?

(The point of my question is why calling SuperClass's constructor in SubClass's constructor body is error)

Comment: How does code 2 "work" if it doesn't compile? And how can code 1 be more efficient than 2?

Comment: I know what you said.. but i don't explain this thing exactly. first, i think code 2 will work without compile error. If they work, the code 1 is more efficient than code 2. Because if the code 2 works, when object instance is instantiated, it calls SuperClass's constructor twice(default constructor and constructor specified in SubClass constructor body). But code 1 calls only specified constructor specified in initializer list. I said this thing.. but my think is incorrect and code 2 has compile error.

Comment: Look, it doesn't compile (which is what I would expect). Are you asking if your compiler has a bug? Or what are you asking?

Comment: Compiler doesn't have any bug. My question is why calling SuperClass's constructor in SubClass's body is error.

Comment: Fine, so what is the point of asking why some code that doesn't compile is more or less efficient than one that does?

Comment: Yes. It is not comparable. that's error in my question. I'll correct. Thanks for your comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
SubClass(int superArg, int subArg) : subVar(subArg) {
    SuperClass(superArg);
}
```

compilers recognize `SuperClass(superArg);` as a declaration
(equivalent to `SuperClass superArg;`),
(whereas I expected a creation of a temporary `SuperClass`).

So you have `superArg` declared once with `int` once with `SuperClass`.

A minimal code to expose your problem:

```
void foo(int arg) { double (arg); }
```

Comment: Then, i will recheck declaration part! i have one more question. I correct code 2 which calls SuperClass default constructor. In this case, code 2 doesn't have error and calls SuperClass default constructor twice. In the result, i think, there is a standard to distinguish between declaration and calling function. how can i get clues of this question?

Comment: or it is also declaration?

Comment: C/C++ has some unintuitive declaration syntax as this one, [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), array reference....

Answer (score 0):

You receive the error because you are trying to declare a local variable of type `SuperClass` with the *same name* as a parameter. Although it *looks* like you are calling the base class constructor you are not. Constructors cannot be directly invoked outside of the initializer list, they are unnamed special member functions.

The parenthesis are valid and are used to avoid the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) problem. This causes decalrations like `SuperClass x();` to be interpreted as a function named `x` that returns a value of type `SuperClass`. The use of parenthesis allows the compiler to deduce that it should instead be a variable.

If your intent is to call the base class constructor you will need to do it in the initializer list.

```
SubClass(int superArg, int subArg) : SuperClass(superArg), subVar(subArg)
{
}
```

If your intent is to create a local varaible of type `SuperClass` you will need to choose a different name.

```
SubClass(int superArg, int subArg) : subVar(subArg)
{
    SuperClass superArgX;
}
```

Comment: But it would be fine (and possibly less confusing) not to use any parentheses at all.

Comment: Yes, in this case it would be fine as long as a different name was used and the intent isn't to call the base class constructor.

Answer (score -1):

You have misplaced your curly braces. Try this:

```
class SubClass : public SuperClass{
private:
    int subVar;
public:
    SubClass() : SuperClass(1),subVar(1) {}
    SubClass(int superArg, int subArg) : subVar(subArg), // { removed, comma added
        SuperClass(superArg) // semicolon removed
    {} // change curly braces like this
    void print(){
        std::cout<<getVar()<<" & "<<subVar<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes your code will work. but your code is same as code 1. And i want to know why code 2 has compile error not correcting the error. Thank you for your answer!